# AngularJS transform a css translation into a directive

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I got a div with this style

```
#main-content{
   height: inherit;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
   transform: translateY(50px);
   transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

#main-content:hover{
   transform: translateY(30px);
   opacity: 0;
}
```

When my mouse hover the div it goes up and disappears, now I would like to remove the hover and execute this animation in a directive.
How can I get the div element and how can add this animation on it ?

EDIT : this is the directive where I would like to add the animation

```
.directive('ngMouseWheelUp', function ($window, $location, $timeout) {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            angular.element($window).bind("DOMMouseScroll mousewheel onmousewheel onscroll", function (event) {
                if (!scope.elementIsScrolled) {
                    var event = window.event || event; // old IE support
                    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (event.wheelDelta || -event.detail)));
                    if (delta > 0) {
                        console.log("wheel up");


                       // This is where I would like to add the animation


                        event.returnValue = false;
                        if (event.preventDefault) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                        scope.$apply();
                        scope.elementIsScrolled = true;
                        $timeout(function () {
                            scope.elementIsScrolled = false;
                        }, 800);
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    })
```

Comment: Why don't you transform that into a class, and then add this class to your elements instead of a directive? so instead of #main-content it would be .hide-on-hover and then add hide-on-hover in class atribute

Comment: I want to do this on a directive because I use a directive for detect when the user mouse wheel scroll and I would like to do this animation when the user scroll

Comment: Okay so when do you want to execute this animation in a directive? at which event?

Comment: I edit my question and add the directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS**

```
#main-content.hovered{
   transform: translateY(30px);
   opacity: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
// This is where I would like to add the animation
angular.element(element).addClass('hovered');
// turns transition-duration:0.5s into 500 miliseconds to use for $timeout
let timeoutDuration = parseFloat(angular.element(element).css('transition-duration')) * 1000;
$timeout(function () {
    angular.element(element).removeClass('hovered');
}, timeoutDuration);
```